# Find all files with given extension which are in folder with files with another extension

Tags: windows, file-management, total-commander

I want to clean automatically created backup `*.bak` files created by certain program. These files could be everywhere. There are also `*.bak` files which I want to keep.

All `*.bak` files which I want to remove are placed in folder together with at least 1 `*.dwg` file.

How to find (and delete) these files? Preferably using Total Commander.

//added 17.12.2021 14:00 CET
Consider:

```
c:\1\
c:\1\x.bak   <remove
c:\1\y.dwg
c:\1\2\x.bak <keep

c:\2\x.bak     <keep
c:\2\2\x.bak   <keep
c:\2\2\3\x.dwg
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a method to filter both for *.bak and *.dwg files. You'll have then to compare the filenames manually and choose what you need to keep.

(Total Commander supports also scripting, either [with PowerPro](http://ppro.totalcmd.net/) or [with WinScript](https://totalcmd.net/plugring/WinScriptAdv.html). Writing a script from scratch would however exceed the scope of this forum  )

In Total Commander, navigate to your base folder / user folder, and perform the following:

- define the filter: <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>F12</kbd>, set `*.bak *.dwg` as filter type
- to toggle branch view: <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>B</kbd> (branch view includes all subfolders)
- Select the files you need to delete (or <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd> to select all)
- Hit <kbd>DEL</kbd>, accept deletion (or <kbd>SHIFT</kbd>+<kbd>DEL</kbd> to avoid the recycle bin)
- to reset filter use <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>F10</kbd>

adapted from [this thread on ghisler.ch (official TC board)](https://ghisler.ch/board/viewtopic.php?t=53692)

You can also create a dedicated filter button, if you use this often: see the above thread.

---

**EDIT**: it could be useful to display the path next to your filenames.

Right-click on the status bar, choose "Custom Colums", then "New". Add a column, and under Field Contents choose "path", or enter `[=tc.path]`, as in the image below

[image]

Comment: But this gives me ALL `*.bak` files (even them what I want to preserve). It's basically equivalent of Windows search for "*.bak" and removing all results.

Comment: @Lluser I see you've updated your question after I've posted my answer: there was no way for me to know.  See my edits. If you want to have something more advanced, [this thread](https://ghisler.ch/board/viewtopic.php?p=136055#136055) might be interesting. If you want an automatic method, do your own research, write a script and come back with your questions about that.

Comment: @Lluser note that your filter can display BOTH *.dwg AND *.bak in the same list

Answer (score 0):

I solved it using PowerShell commnad (command-chain)

Here is a single line version:

```bash
[array]$dirs = (Get-Item .); $dirs += Get-ChildItem -Directory -Recurse; forEach ($dir in $dirs){$files = Get-ChildItem -path $dir.fullname -filter "*.bak"; if ((Get-ChildItem -Path $dir.fullname -filter "*.dwg").count -gt 0){foreach ($delfile in $files){Write-Host $delfile.fullname;<# $delfile.delete()  #>}}}
```

**It does not delete anything until you remove comment (`<# #>`) around the last command.**

### Explanation:

```bash
# Create an array with current folder and all (non-empty) subfolders
[array]$dirs = (Get-Item .); $dirs += Get-ChildItem -Directory -Recurse

# For each element in the array (folder)
foreach ($dir in $dirs){
  #Get all files ending with .bak
  $files = Get-ChildItem -path $dir.fullname -filter "*.bak"
  
  # If there is more than 0 files ending with .dwg
  if ((Get-ChildItem -Path $dir.fullname -filter "*.dwg").count -gt 0){
    # For each file ending with .bak
    foreach ($delfile in $files){
      # Write a path of the file
      Write-Host $delfile.fullname
      # Permanently delete the file
      $delfile.delete()
    }
  }
}
```